# How to add button link in controller.rb - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

After users sign up at my site, they need to activate their account. An email will be sent to the user. The user will not be able to log in if the account is not activated.

A Message will show that says: "Account is not activated. Check your email for an activation link." How do I create a link or button in the warning message that prompts the server to send another activation email to the user?

I tried `action_item`, `<%=`, `button_to`, etc.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    if user.activated?
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      message  = "Account not activated. "
      message += "Check your email for the activation link. "
      flash[:warning] = message 
      action_item :view, only: :show do 
      link_to 'Resend the activation link.', :action => "@user.send_password_reset_email", :controller => "PasswordResets"
    end
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: are you using devise to handle email confirmation?

Comment: nope. I'm not using devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mistakes which I've spotted:

You will place a `link_to` helper in folder: app/views/* only

so if you try placing this in a html.erb file, you should be able to see the link being generated

```
 link_to 'Resend the activation link.', :action => "try_resend", :controller => "PasswordResets"
```

for controller:

```
class PasswordResets < ApplicationController
  def try_resend
    puts 'You should see this in console' 
  end
end
```